# Spring treating servlet contextConfigLocation class as path despite correct contextClass

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jersey

We're using JavaConfig, and I'm trying to set up a separate application context to get around some issues in Jersey 1.7 (namely, the way it includes all Spring beans annotated with @Controller in all paths).

I've set the SpringServlet I want to use the separate application context up like so:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.admin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.AdminWebConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

However, Spring keeps giving me the following error when I try to hit one of the services; it's trying to treat my class name as a file path:

```
[2015-08-07 11:52:20,081] [ERROR] [] [request=] [user=] [ip=] [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/my-app].
[My REST Service]] [Allocate exception for servlet My REST Service] java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/com.mycompany.AdminWebConfig]
```

Any thoughts? I thought setting contextClass to org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext would make it recognize that as a class name, but it doesn't seem to be doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) has [support for `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#DispatcherServlet--). But you're not using the `DispatcherServlet`, you're using some Jersey [`SpringServlet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-spring/1.19/com/sun/jersey/spi/spring/container/servlet/SpringServlet.java?av=f).

[It explicitly creates an `XmlWebApplicationContext`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-spring/1.19/com/sun/jersey/spi/spring/container/servlet/SpringServlet.java?av=f#170).

Comment: Bah, so it does. Anyone have any ideas for working around this? Jersey 1 is proving to be pretty painful.

Comment: @gdmitchell Extend the class and add the behavior that loads the `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` (if you want to keep using Jersey).

Comment: I'll see what I can do. We're moving away from Jersey, so having to hack it a bit might not be a huge problem.